# Using PC to control Android (ex : using mouse or keyboard to tilt, rotate, emulate gyroscope, etc)

Tags: keyboard, remote-control, sensors, gyroscope

Is there any way to input fake sensor data **from** PC **into** your android phone (not the opposite)? Like using WASD from PC to make your android phone thinking they are being tilted, rotated, etc even though they actually aren't.

I want to try google cardboard applications. Most of them require gyroscope in order to run properly. Sadly my phone doesn't have gyroscope installed in it.

I'm thinking if there's already a bunch of options to use the data from the sensors from an android phone to do a lot of things in PC (joystick, etc), why not the opposite?